# replace only replaces 1 char at time for jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a small plugin that replaces chars using regexp. If I delete more than 1 char in textbox and blur, it only removes that char. It doesnt "mirror" the value from the textbox and has it current value it seems.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.friendlyUrl = function (destinationID) {
        return this.blur(function () {
            var title = $(this).val();

            var url = title
                    .replace(/[åä]/g, "a")
                    .replace(/[ÅÄ]/g, "A")
                    .replace(/ö/g, "o")
                    .replace(/Ö/g, "O")
                    .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "-")
                    .replace(/^-+/, "")
                    .replace(/-+$/, "")
                    .replace(/-+/g, "-")
                    .toLowerCase();

            $(destinationID).val(url);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And I call it using:

```
$("#PageName").friendlyUrl("#Url");
```

What might be wrong here?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle please?

Comment: Note that you're missing the `g` flag to perform a global match in `.replace(/^-+/, "").replace(/-+$/, "")`. That's probably not the source of your problem though.

Comment: campari: that was the problem :) can you create an answer so I can give you points? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some modifications.

Assuming that is the input to enter the url:

```
<input type="text" id="PageName"/>
```

The plugin code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.friendlyUrl = function () {
        return this.blur(function () {
            var title = $(this).val();

            var url = title
                    .replace(/[åä]/g, "a")
                    .replace(/[ÅÄ]/g, "A")
                    .replace(/ö/g, "o")
                    .replace(/Ö/g, "O")
                    .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "-")
                    .replace(/^-+/g, "")
                    .replace(/-+$/g, "")
                    .replace(/-+/g, "-")
                    .toLowerCase();

            $(this).val(url);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

and the call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#PageName").friendlyUrl();
});
```

You don't really need to pass id here

Try [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bQ5X3/2/)

Comment: I guess the output field should be a different than the input field - that's what the selector parameter is for.

Comment: That fiddle works. Must be something interfering with my production page.... since it replaces half of the values I erase. Thanks. I'll look more deeply into the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that `url` is used anywhere so It seems to me that you're trying to do this

```
$(destinationID).val(url);
```

Comment: Edited it, same problem still :)